# ArcGIS REST Services Directory url without the port 6080

Tags: arcgis-server

I am wondering if I could access the GIS server URL `http://gisserver.domain.com:6080/arcgis` without the port(6080) such as `http://gisserver.domain.com/arcgis`. I was told that [Using a reverse proxy server with ArcGIS Server](http://server.arcgis.com/en/server/10.3/administer/windows/using-a-reverse-proxy-server-with-arcgis-server.htm). I am wondering if anyone could provide your experience how to hide the port.

The background of my server

ArcGIS server 10.3.1 (No Web Adaptor installed)

I have Windows 2012 Server x64 with SQL Server 2012.

I'm also using IIS 8 as a web server on the same machine.

It is the security issue. In my case, I have enabled the windows authentication for the website "gisserver.domain.com";. However, the window authentication does not work when I type the "gisserver.domain.com:6080";. I have set the inbound rule in the firewall setting inside the server, which opens the port 6080 and 6443 to the public. I was always told to use the Web Adaptor to address this issue. I am wondering if there are other methods to address this issue in the IIS or firewall setting.

Comment: What is your reason for needing to hide the port?  Are you having issues with that port, or is it a security reason?

Comment: I appreciate your information. It is the security sissue. for my case, I have enabled the windows authentication for the website "http://gisserver.domain.com". However, the window authentication does not work when I type the "http://gisserver.domain.com:6080". I have set the inbound rule in the firewall setting inside the server, which opens the port 6080 and 6443 to the public. I was always told to use the Web Adaptor to address this issue. I am wondering if there are other methods to address this issue in the IIS or firewall setting.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include this information

Comment: This is the purpose of the Web Adaptor. You either need it, or to code your own equivalent (with domain integration, expect that to take a month or two (or three))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Installing a web adaptor is the appropriate way to resolve this problem.  Is there a reason you don't want to install a web adaptor?  The purpose of the web adaptor is to pass requests from standard web ports (e.g. 80/443) and create a communication link to your server and resolve issues like the one you're dealing with:

Internet/outside -> firewall -> load balancer -> server -> IIS (Port 80) -> Web Adaptor -> ArcGIS Server (Port 6080).

Comment: I appreciate your apply. I have a quick question if I could install the web adaptor java version on the windows server 2012 R2.

Comment: What do you mean by the web adaptor java version?  You should have a Windows web adaptor install that comes with the ArcGIS Server download.  It's just a double-click, extract, install and then you need to configure it to point to your ArcGIS Server.

Comment: I appreciate your quick update. I feel there should be a way other than the web adaptor to address this issue. Therefore, I could know how to serve the data out from other servers without the port (ex. open source) in the future.

Comment: Honestly, what you're saying doesn't seem to make a lot of sense.  I think you need to be more clear on what you're attempting to do.  I see you have asked the same questions in another thread and received similar answers.

Comment: Hi MapLion, I followed your instructions and have installed the WebAdaptor. The port 6080 was hidden. The rest service directory is created ("http://stateparkmap.okstate.edu/ousgeog/rest/") with the active windows authentication. However, the public still can access the default rest directory (http://stateparkmap.okstate.edu:6080/arcgis/rest/) without any username and password inputs. In addition, I have created the inbound rule to allow the port 6080/6443 in the server firewall. Could you tell me how I only allow the directory work ("http://stateparkmap.okstate.edu/ousgeog/rest/") ?

Comment: Okay, if I understand you correctly, first you should remove your inbound rule for your firewall; that will block the public from being able to access your rest directory using port 6080.  They should be coming into your server through the standard web ports (80 in this case) and your Web Adaptor handles the routing from there to the ArcGIS Server (6080 in this case).

Comment: After that, depending on your setup, you can limit access to the REST services directly with the server, or through IIS when it hits a web service that talks to the server (e.g. apps made with Web AppBuilder).